# Swift 3 Firebase data retrieve error: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1a8e00d50) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1a8e01c78)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I am new with Firebase and I got problem with getting data from database, I get error on this line:

```
      let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Could you help me with fixing this problem?

**Error says:**

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1a8e00d50) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1a8e01c78).
```

**event controller:**

```
  init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
key = snapshot.key


let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
addedByUser = snapshotValue["addedByUser"] as! String
startTime = snapshotValue["startTime"] as! Double
endPickerTime = snapshotValue["endPickerTime"] as! Double
longtitude = snapshotValue["longtitude"] as! Double
latitude = snapshotValue["latitude"] as! Double

eventImageStringUrl = snapshotValue["eventImageStringUrl"] as! String
eventId = snapshotValue["eventId"] as! String
eventDescription = snapshotValue["eventDescription"] as! String
completed = snapshotValue["completed"] as! Bool
ref = snapshot.ref
 }
```

**Getting data from database:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("events").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    var newItems: [Event] = []
    for item in snapshot.children {

     let event = Event(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
     newItems.append(event)
    }


  })
```

**Database scheme:**

[image]

Comment: The compiler says `snapshot.value` is a string.

Comment: Try to change .childAdded to .value in .observe. Has it helped?

Comment: It seems `FIRDataSnapshot value` is `String`

Comment: @VladPulichev Thank you, you solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.childAdded` to `.value` in `.observe`.